# Buying QQQ vs QQQM

Tags: united-states, stock-markets, etf, nasdaq

Recently there is a new ETF to track the Nasdaq 100. Its symbol is QQQM. It is very similar to QQQ and it has lower expense ratio. I understand that QQQ is better known and has a smaller spread between the bid and the ask. For somebody who is going to buy and hold for a long period of time, a larger bid ask spread does not seem like a big deal to me.

Other than the larger bid ask spread, is there any other advantage to QQQ over QQQM?

I am in the United States.

Comment: it's a "M" mini fund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Invesco designed the new
> QQQM to appeal to buy-and-hold investors, while traders and institutional buyers may
> prefer to stick with the original QQQ.

> Let’s explain. For starters, the new fund is cheaper. QQQM (affectionately known as the
> Q mini) has a lower management fee. Shares of the Q mini are also a fraction of the
> value of QQQ, putting the mini within reach of small savers who might balk at QQQ’s
> price tag.

[Source](https://etfdb.com/etf/QQQM/#etf-ticker-profile)

Comment: Who affectionately names ETFs?

Comment: LOL on that one @RonJohn

Comment: There are some postings on this site saying that the fifth character in an ETF's name has a special meaning. The first four characters belong to the ETF company.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points that indicates there could be some positives of QQQM.

- dividend distributions could be treated as qualified dividends than regular income
- no potential end date
- lower expense ratio: .15% compared to QQQ's .20%

Only Con seems is : liquidity

Source : [seekingalpha article](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4395534-qqqm-worth-watching-hold-off-on-buying-for-now)